# Why does the following Clojure not detect a palindrome?

Tags: string, clojure, comparison, palindrome

I'm just trying to convert to a string and compare to the reverse

```
(defn is-palindrome? [num]
  (= (str num) (reverse (str num))))
```

Something like

```
(is-palindrome 1221)
```

Is returning false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(defn palindrome? [num]
  (= (seq (str num)) (clojure.string/reverse (str num))))
```

Comment: reverse is linear time for a seq.  It's better to use clojure.string/reverse to reverse the String.  If you already have a vector, rseq is constant time for a vector.

Answer (score 10):

Try this instead:

```
(defn is-palindrome? [num]
  (= (str num) (apply str (reverse (str num)))))
```

In your code, the expression `(reverse (str 1221))` returns the list of characters `(\1 \2 \2 \1)`, which needs to be turned back into a string for the comparison to work. Alternatively, you could convert both numbers to character lists and perform a list comparison instead:

```
(defn is-palindrome? [num]
  (= (seq (str num)) (reverse (str num))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code returns false because it is comparing a string with a sequence, which can never be equal.

You can make it work by explicitly converting the string into a seq as follows:

```
(defn is-palindrome? [num] 
  (let [digit-sequence (seq (str num))]
    (= digit-sequence (reverse digit-sequence))))
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the the overhead of manipulating collections of characters dominates, so it's actually faster to compare the original string to a reversed version even though it seems like you're comparing twice as many characters as necessary.  Make sure you use clojure.string/reverse, not clojure.core/reverse.  The usual Clojure convention is to end a predicate with a question mark, but not to use the "is" prefix.

```
(require 'clojure.string)

(defn palindrome? [s] (= s (clojure.string/reverse s)))
(defn palindrome-num? [n] (palindrome? (str n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(reverse (str 1221))
```

returns a List of characters

```
(\1 \2 \2 \1)
```

but (str 1221) is a java String